# Could not find method apt() for arguments while adding ButterKnife

Tags: java, android, butterknife

After adding 
`compile com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.0.1` and
`apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.1.0'`
lines in gradle I am getting  below error

> Error:(31, 0) Could not find method apt() for arguments [com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.0.1] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please be aware that version 8.0.1 is not the latest version of butterknife.

As of today, the projects [github page](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife) states that you have to add the following to your build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`apt` was used with custom plugin `com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt` before Android Gradle plugin 2.2

If you use Android Gradle 2.2 plugin or newer, then you should remove `com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt` from your Gradle plugins.
And change all `apt` in dependencies to `annotationProcessor`

You can read more [here](https://bitbucket.org/hvisser/android-apt/wiki/Migration)